# How can I optimize the code, taking converted_data dynamically instead of fix size 6

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def preprocess_pattern_data(converted_data):
        corpus_1 = []
        corpus_2 = []
        corpus_3 = []
        corpus_4 = []
        corpus_5 = [] 
        corpus_6 = []
        c_1 = []
        c_2 = []
        c_3 = []
        c_4 = []
        c_5 = []
        c_6 = []
        doc = converted_data[0].split(",")
        for i in range(len(doc)):
            review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', doc[i])
            review = review.split()
            review = [word for word in review if not word in custom_stopwords]
            review = ''.join(review)
            corpus_1.append(review)

        for i in corpus_1:
            if i == '':
                corpus_1.remove('')
            else:
                c_1.append(i)

        sentence_1 = ' '.join(word for word in c_1) 

        doc = converted_data[1].split(",")
        for j in range(len(doc)):
            review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', doc[j])
            review = review.split()
            review = [word for word in review if not word in custom_stopwords]
            review = ''.join(review)
            corpus_2.append(review)

        for i in corpus_2:
            if i == '':
                corpus_2.remove('')
            else:
                c_2.append(i)

        sentence_2 = ' '.join(word for word in c_2) 

        doc = converted_data[2].split(",")
        for k in range(len(doc)):
            review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', doc[k])
            review = review.split()
            review = [word for word in review if not word in custom_stopwords]
            review = ''.join(review)
            corpus_3.append(review)
        for i in corpus_3:
            if i == '':
                corpus_3.remove('')
            else:
                c_3.append(i)

        sentence_3 = ' '.join(word for word in c_3) 

        doc = converted_data[3].split(",")
        for l in range(len(doc)):
            review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', doc[l])
            review = review.split()
            review = [word for word in review if not word in custom_stopwords]
            review = ''.join(review)
            corpus_4.append(review)
        for i in corpus_4:
            if i == '':
                corpus_4.remove('')
            else:
                c_4.append(i)

        sentence_4 = ' '.join(word for word in c_4) 

        doc = converted_data[4].split(",")
        for m in range(len(doc)):
            review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', doc[m])
            review = review.split()
            review = [word for word in review if not word in custom_stopwords]
            review = ''.join(review)
            corpus_5.append(review)
        for i in corpus_5:
            if i == '':
                corpus_5.remove('')
            else:
                c_5.append(i)

        sentence_5 = ' '.join(word for word in c_5) 

        doc = converted_data[5].split(",")
        for n in range(len(doc)):
            review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', doc[n])
            review = review.split()
            review = [word for word in review if not word in custom_stopwords]
            review = ''.join(review)
            corpus_6.append(review)
        for i in corpus_6:
            if i == '':
                corpus_6.remove('')
            else:
                c_6.append(i)

        sentence_6 = ' '.join(word for word in c_6) 

        sentences = [sentence_1, sentence_2, sentence_3, sentence_4, sentence_5, sentence_6]

        return sentences
```

Please help me optimize the code, I want it to be dynamic to take length of converted text and loop through the code. Here i have taken six list and appended my code using static 6 list but i want it to be dynamic and take length from the converted_text loop the length of converted text and append it to sentences.

I tried with this code, but the problem is all the six sentences which I created join together within one list, so if I do sentences[0] I just getting first word instead of first whole sentence.

```
def preprocess_pattern_data(converted_data):
    corpus = []
    c = []
    sentences = []
    
    for i in range(len(converted_data)):
        
        doc = converted_data[i].split(',')
        
        for j in range(len(doc)):
            review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', doc[j])
            review = review.split()
            review = [word for word in review if not word in custom_stopwords]
            review = ''.join(review)
            corpus.append(review)

    for k in corpus:
        if k == '':
            corpus.remove('')
        else:
            c.append(k)

    sent = ' '.join(word for word in c)
    sentences.append(sent)
        
    return sentences

pattern_sentences = preprocess_pattern_data(converted_data)
print(pattern_sentences)
```

Comment: Use a list of lists. `corpus_1`, `corpus_2` and so on should all be elements of a list.

Comment: c_1, c_2 -> c[], and every index represent your c_n list. Or you can use a dictionary and name them like corpus = {'corpus_1':[], 'corpus_2':[] ... }

Comment: I tried but not getting proper output.

Comment: @Yuri, Again its fixed to six even if I put into dictionary .

Comment: Show us the modified code.

Comment: I have pasted my code below original code.

Comment: for k in corpus: <- indent this to go under the "for i in range(len(converted_data)):" loop. Now it is outside, it is obvious that the first loop collect everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this? It is not clear what you want to do but this should put you on the right track.

There are a couple of problems in your script:

- "word not in" instead of "not word in"
- maybe you forgot to reset the variables (c, corpus) at every cicle?

This is the code:

```
import re

custom_stopwords = ['and', 'or']
converted_data = ['one, two, three', 'four,five,six']

def preprocess_pattern_data(converted_data):
    sentences = []
    for i in range(len(converted_data)):
        sent = ''
        corpus = []
        c = []
        doc = converted_data[i].split(',')
        for j in range(len(doc)):
            review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', doc[j])
            review = review.split()
            review = [word for word in review if word not in custom_stopwords]
            review = ''.join(review)
            corpus.append(review)
        for k in corpus:
            if k == '':
                corpus.remove('')
            else:
                c.append(k)
        sent = ' '.join(word for word in c)
        sentences.append(sent)
    return sentences

pattern_sentences = preprocess_pattern_data(converted_data)
print(pattern_sentences)
```

this output:

```
['one two three', 'four five six']
```